# How to fix Bootstrap theme overlapping on views administration pages

Tags: 7, views, theming

Using bootstrap as an administration theme. Required rather than seven because of the way we are getting people to contribute to the site.

Under views contextual filters, they layout falls apart. Anybody solved this? See under "Path component".

I have tried debugging the page and setting clear:both everywhere etc.

[image]

Comment: [Adminimal theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme) is the best admin theme for Drupal,try it instead of any theme else.

Comment: Bootstrap theme is not designed for admin pages. You have to take a lot of effort to fix those minor style fault if you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set the admin theme just for views in the views settings page: admin/structure/views/settings. "Custom admin theme for the Views UI".

This does not fix the bootstrap theme problem, but it does solve my problem where I want to use the bootstrap theme for content administration actions.

Secondly, to solve my problem where I want a consistent user interface when viewing and editing content under admin/appearance there is a setting

```
Use the administration theme when editing or creating content.
```

This enables me to provide people submitting content with the same experience as viewing.